# What does the symbol -> in Python mean?

Tags: python

What does -> do in Python?  Can't seem to find anything with a search.  Most I can guess is that it creates an alias of some kind.

```
def function(parameters) -> str
```

or

```
format(...)
      S.format(*args, **kwargs) -> str
```

Comment: Thanks for the links to existing answers.  How come when I search for "python ->" or "python '->'" they don't come up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python 3.5+ optioinal typing was included. Mypy is the library used for extra typing support. After a function declaration "->" is used to specify the type of what the function returns.

Comment: http://mypy-lang.org/